# getting errors when building react-native-tvos app

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build, react-native-tvos

when building a react native tv-os app using eas build -p android command i get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking/scripts/android/autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 377
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-av'.
   > [CXX1102] Location specified by ndk.dir (C://Users//souilmi//AppData//Local//Android//Sdk//ndk//25.1.8937393) did not contain a valid NDK and couldn't be used
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle' line: 65
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================
BUILD FAILED in 2m 10s
10 actionable tasks: 10 executed
```

the app builds fine in local and runs on an emulator
these are my specs:

```
Gradle 8.3.
Node v18.13.0
react-native-tvos V0.73.2-0
Expo V50.0.4
```

what i'm i doing wrong?